# Networking - Install wifi Adapter HP laptop Ubuntu 18.10 rtl8723be

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.10, rtl8723be

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu from 17.10 to 18.10 and I have lost my WiFi adapter drivers I can't see WiFi option in the menu list. I have tried installing drives from repo https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new but I guess I have messed my entire network setting. Please help.

[image: WIFI Missing in menu list IMG]

Comment: If you followed the tutorial to the latter did you restart your system just incase?

Comment: yes after every process i have restarted the system

Comment: if you run `sudo lsmod | grep -i rtl8723be` is it listed?

Comment: Thanx Buddy issue is solved. The problem was with the secure boot option. After disabling secure boot from BIOS WIFI option was visible then I have followed these steps suggested by @Manikandan 

https://connectwww.com/how-to-solve-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-problem-in-ubuntu/4625/ for weak signal problem

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen just have a question is it good to disable Secure Boot from Bios..?

Comment: Whemn using a non-native Ubuntu install as most of us do then you have to disable secure boot to get Ubuntu to work. It's ok just mind what you install! Please kindly post an answer for others who may have similar issues, after posting wait like 5mins then accept your answer by clicking on the check mark to the left!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GitHub repository link for Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier returns 404 Not Found now. It seems it has been removed. On Ubuntu 19.04 and later you don't need to download drivers from GitHub anymore.

---

#### 18.04 and earlier

Realtek RTL8723BE wireless network adapter has problems managing the antenna in Ubuntu which leads to weak wifi signal problems. To fix it follow these steps.

1. Disable the Secure Boot option in the UEFI setup utility in order to make the wifi option visible in Ubuntu.
2. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   iwconfig
   ```
3. Note down the wlp number. In this example it's *wlp13s0*.
4. Go to [this link](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new), download the driver zip file to your desktop, and unzip the archive.
5. Run these commands from the terminal.

   ```
   cd ~/Desktop  
   cd rtlwifi_new-master  
   make  
   sudo make install  
   sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be  
   sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2  
   sudo ip link set wlp13s0 up  
   sudo iw dev wlp13s0 scan
   ```
6. Run the following command to make the settings permanent.

   ```
   echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8723be.conf
   ```

Comment: The rock bt coex branch has been abandoned, https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/commit/f5c1523f9b20a16ca5e946d0ec5ec622feaf16ea  It was merged with master branch a few years ago

Comment: The Github repo link is giving 404 now, seems it is deleted or renamed. Is there any alternative to it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below instruction for installing rtl8723be driver.

git clone https://github.com/jodhpurlaxman/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh

Check Signal strength using the below commands.

DEVICE=$(iw dev | grep Interface | cut -d " " -f2)
sudo iw dev $DEVICE scan | egrep "SSID|signal|(on"

If the signal for the AP to which you wish to connect is -60 or less, then you have problem.
Fix the signal strength by changing the "ant_sel" option(1,2,3,4,5) in install.sh file and re-run **sudo ./install.sh** command and check signal strength again.

Comment: According to the README.md instructions at your GitHub link: *If your kernel is 4.17 or newer (eoan, focal, and later releases), AND your card is not an RTL8723DE, then you should NOT be using the external driver. The built-in one is the same.* The currently supported versions of Ubuntu that this answer applies to are now 16.04 and 18.04.